# Copy column value from a dataframe to another if values are equal

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have two dataframes like that (this is an example because my dataframes are complex) :

```
lst_p = [['2', 0], ['3', 1], ['4', 0], ['5', 0]]  
df_p = pd.DataFrame(lst_p, columns =['id', 'redness'])



lst_c = [['apple', 2], ['orange', 2], ['banana', 3], ['kiwi', 4], ['cherry', 5]]  
df_c = `pd.DataFrame(lst_c, columns =['name', 'id'])`
```

**My two dataframes don't have the same length.**

As you can see in my second df_c, some 'id' appears 2 times. (for id=2)

I would like to create a new column in my `df_c` that copy the value `'redness' of my df_p` if `'id'` from my df_c == 'id' from my `df_p`.

I don't know if it's very clear...

Thanks a LOT !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple **[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)** will do the trick:

One issue that you have is that in one dataframe your `id` is of type `string`, 
and in the other dataframe, the `id` is of type `int`.

The easiest way to resolve this is to convert the string to int **before merge**, 
and convert back if so desired.

#### Code:

```
df_p.id = df_p.id.astype(int)
df_c = pd.merge(df_c, df_p, on=['id'], how='left')

print(df_c)
```

#### Output:

[image: df_c]

Answer (score 0):

Use can simply try to convert df_p two column to dictionary any using lambda look for each id's redness, and create new column.

Code:

```
df_c['redness'] = df_c['id'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df_p.redness.values,index=df_p.id).to_dict()[str(x)])
df_c
```